# Avoid Windows Modal Loops

Tags: c++, windows, modal-dialog

I tried to make a Window for OpenGL/Vulkan but every time I resize/move it the program just breaks there until the resize/move is done. 
After some research I found out that the modal loops from windows are blocking

Also, a modal loop is called when I just click on maximize/minimize/close button and hold it or the window menu is open

So my question is how to avoid these modal loops? Can I do, what the modal loop is doing, myself ?

Edit: 
I already tried to use timers but this does not work with maximize/minimize/close button

Comment: "*how to avoid these modal loops?*" - you can't, they are built in to the OS itself in the way it manages windows. "*Can I do, what the modal loop is doing, myself?*" - and what would that solve exactly? You would end up having to implement your own modal loops. And besides, there are some things done inside the OS modal loops that are simply not exposed in friendly APIs to user code. So no, you can't do *everything* the OS does.

Comment: "and what would that solve exactly?" -So i can keep my own loop running and rendering stuff

Comment: You could simply start a UI timer (via `SetTimer()`) and let the OS modal loops dispatch `WM_TIMER` messages to you while they are running. Or, you can use `WH_MSGFILTER`/`WH_SYSMSGFILTER` hooks (via `SetWindowsHookEx()`), which are called during modal loops. See [Message Pumping and Moving/Sizing Modal Loops](https://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.ui.narkive.com/MzflQf5e/)

Comment: Jeah i tried the Timer thing and it worked for resize/move but not for the window menu for example

Comment: It should be working, since menus have to process window messages, too

Comment: Okay i checked it, it works with resize/move/window-menu but not with maximize/minimize/close buttons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213745/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-dergaijin).