# How to prevent Timer from freezing when titlebar is clicked or dragging?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019

I have a timer that is responsible for displaying the GIF image frame by frame. I noticed that when I `right-clicked` and `hold` the `titilebar` the timer pause for I think 1 second and when I `left-clicked`  and `hold` the titlebar`, the timer pause until I released the mouse.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GDIHelper::StaticControlProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {
    switch(uMsg) {
        case WM_TIMER:
        {
            OnTimer(); // Do something on timer.
            InvalidateRect(staticControl, NULL, FALSE);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
           
            Graphics g(hdc);
            g.DrawImage(m_pImage, 0, 0, width, height);

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return TRUE; 
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(message) {
        case WM_CREATE: {
            staticControl = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_OWNERDRAW, xPosition, yPosition, width, height, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL); //create the static control.
            SetWindowSubclass(staticControl, &StaticControlProc, unique_id, 0);
            
            gdiHelper.AnimateGIF();
            
            break;
        }
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            HDC hdc;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            //Paint other images and text here...
            
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            gdiHelper.Destroy();
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

and here are the functions responsible for creating the timer.

```
void GDIHelper::OnTimer() {
    if(isPlayable) {
        GUID Guid = FrameDimensionTime;
        m_pImage->SelectActiveFrame(&Guid, m_iCurrentFrame);        
        m_iCurrentFrame = (++m_iCurrentFrame) % m_FrameCount;
    }
}

void GDIHelper::AnimateGIF() {
    if(m_bIsPlaying == TRUE) {
        return;
    }
    
    m_iCurrentFrame = 0;
    GUID Guid = FrameDimensionTime;
    m_pImage->SelectActiveFrame(&Guid, m_iCurrentFrame);
    SetTimer(staticControl, 120, ((UINT*)m_pItem[0].value)[m_iCurrentFrame] * 10, NULL);
    ++m_iCurrentFrame;
    m_bIsPlaying = TRUE;
}
```

How to possibly prevent that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764702/avoid-windows-modal-loops

Comment: Can't be changed. You'll have the same effect when opening a menu or resizing the window. That's just how the system works.

Comment: It probably possible if you remove the titlebar and create a custom one.

Comment: Is there really nothing I can do about it?

Comment: @Papilion You only need to open an additional thread to control the timer, and this is the easiest way.

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT - Can you give me more details? Perhaps an example?

Comment: Use `CreateThread `or `class thread` and set the function that triggers the timer in the thread, so you don't need to use `SetTimer`, just call `Sleep` or `WaitForSingleObject` to achieve the timing effect.

Comment: @Papilion you didn't show the code that is creating the timer. Please provide a [mcve]. System actions, like holding down on the titlebar to perform a window drag, will block your main message loop, but they run their own secondary message loops, window messages like `WM_TIMER` will still be dispatched properly. So something else has to be going on that we can't see in your code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I think it's unnecessary to provide it, but sure, I updated my question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Inside a `WM_PAINT` handler is absolutely the *wrong* place to be calling `SetTimer()` or `InvalidateRect()`. You should call `SetTimer()` the 1st time in the `WM_CREATE` handler where you are creating and subclassing the `STATIC` control. And calling `InvalidateRect()` only inside your `WM_TIMER` callback. And, unless you are changing the timer's ID or interval, there is no need to kill and recreate the timer inside the `WM_TIMER` callback. Oh, and you are leaking the subclass, as [you are never calling `RemoveWindowSubclass()`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883)

Comment: Is that so? I'll try it. Anyway, I did use `RemoveWindowSubclass` in my WM_DESTROY in `WndProc` callback, I just didn't put it to make the code short here in my post.

Comment: gdiHelper.Destroy(); is responsible for `RemoveWindowSubclass`.

Comment: Well, that makes the code short and clean, but no, it didn't fix the issue. I'm still working on the thread that said by @SongZhu-MSFT though.

Comment: @Papilion Could you post an answer to end this thread.It will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT  No, I couldn't. Not unless I finally solve it.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The `InvalidateRect()` will not immediately redraw your control.  It will simply schedule a future redraw for a specific rectangular area of the window. Making the animation freeze when you clicked or hold on the titlebar.</strike> Use `InvalidateRect()` followed by `UpdateWindow()`, this will forcefully perform immediate redrawing of the specified area of the window.

But it won't just solve the issue. Forget about your timer and use a non-blocking thread instead together with `InvalidateRect()` and `UpdateWindow()`.

```
int animation_duration = 0;

void GDIHelper::TheAnimation() { //This function should be static.
    if(m_bIsPlaying == TRUE) {
        return;
    }
    
    m_iCurrentFrame = 0;
    GUID Guid = FrameDimensionTime;
    m_pImage->SelectActiveFrame(&Guid, m_iCurrentFrame);
    ++m_iCurrentFrame;
    m_bIsPlaying = TRUE;
    animation_duration = ((UINT*)m_pItem[0].value)[m_iCurrentFrame] * 10;
    
    while(isPlayable) { //Make sure to set isPlayable to false on destroy to stop this thread.
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(animation_duration)); //instead of timer, use sleep.
        
        m_pImage->SelectActiveFrame(&Guid, m_iCurrentFrame);
        m_iCurrentFrame = (++m_iCurrentFrame) % m_FrameCount;
        
        InvalidateRect(staticControl, NULL, FALSE);
        UpdateWindow(staticControl); //perform immediate redrawing
    }                                                                                               
}

LRESULT CALLBACK GDIHelper::StaticControlProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {
    switch(uMsg) {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
           
            Graphics g(hdc);
            g.DrawImage(m_pImage, 0, 0, width, height); //draw your image.

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return TRUE; 
        }
        ....
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Then just start the thread and use `detach()` for non-blocking UI.

```
std::thread t(TheAnimation);
t.detach(); // this will be non-blocking thread.
```

Read the comments in the code for some clarification and don't forget to set `isPlayable` to `false` on destroy to stop the thread.